# EntityCommandExecutionException: Invalid column name 'Entity_Id'

Tags: .net, entity-framework

### Background

I'm using Entity Framework's Fluent API to map entities to a database.

#### Entities

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesOrder SalesOrder { get; set; }
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TicketLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}

public class TicketLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
}
```

#### Mapping

```
public class TicketMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ticket>
{
    public TicketMap() {}
}

public class SalesOrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SalesOrder>
{
    public SalesOrderMap()
    {
        HasMany(t => t.Tickets)
            .WithRequired(t => t.SalesOrder)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.SalesOrderId);
    }
}

public class TicketLineMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TicketLine>
{
    public TicketLineMap() {}
}
```

### Problem

When I run a query related to `Ticket`, I receive the following `EntityCommandExecutionException`:

> Invalid column name 'Ticket_Id'.

### What I've Tried

1. Making sure that all entities that reference `Ticket` have their relationships defined
2. Making sure there aren't any duplicate navigation properties
3. Checking other answers for this exception on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I'd forgotten to tell Entity Framework how to associate `Ticket`s with `TicketLine`s.

I resolved it by configuring the relationship:

```
HasMany(t => t.Lines)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Ticket)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.TicketId);
```